# Median in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate the median of the below data frame

```
index t1 t2 t3 t4
    10  1  4  7 10
    20  2  5  8 11
    30  3  6  9  0
    40  1  0  0  0
```

I follow the following steps:

Step 1: Sum by column

```
index  t1   t2  t3  t4  sum
    10  1    4   7   10  22
    20  2    5   8   11  26
    30  3    6   9   0   18
    40  0    1   0   0   1
```

Step2: sort sum variable

```
index  t1   t2  t3  t4  sum
   40  0    0   0   10  1
   30  3    6   9   0   18
   10  1    4   7   10  22
   20  2    5   8   11  26
```

Step 3: Calculate the median of the index variable

```
median of index = (30 + 10) / 2 =20
```

Step 4: Return the specific index value

```
Median(df)=20
```

I don't know how to calculate step 3 and step 4.

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(index=c (10,20,30,40), 
                   t1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1), 
                   t2 = c(4, 5, 6, 0), 
                   t3 = c(7, 8,9,  0),
                   t4 = c(10, 11, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
                                                            
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not well defined, so I took some liberties

1. `df$sum=rowSums(subset(df,select=-c(index)))`
2. `df=df[order(df$sum),]`
3. `idx=median(df$index)` (your calculation is "wrong")
4. `which.min(abs(df$index-idx))`

which returns 2, the index which is closest to the "median" index, in the sorted dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use sapply and the median function.  Example using mtcars:

```
medians <- sapply(mtcars, median)
```

Yields the vector of medians with element names equal to the column names each median came from.